# Difference between two dates with one date as timestamp without time zone

Tags: sql

I want to compute the difference of year between today's date and date of variable called "creation date" which is a timestamp without time zone.
This is the code I used. However, it returned this error "syntax error at or near ")"". I have no idea why.

`select DATEDIFF(year, ('2020/01/01', to_date (created_at, 'YYYY/MM/DD') ))`

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) You have a misplaced parentheses.  (3) I'm not sure if the syntax will work in any database, even if you fix the parentheses.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply ! I am using this website mode analytics https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(curdate(), created_at);
```

`DATEDIFF` function will return the number of days between two dates.
`curdate()` will give you the current date.

If that does not work, try this:

```
DATEDIFF(year, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, created_at)
```

Or this:

```
SELECT DATE_PART('year', CURRENT_DATE) - DATE_PART('year', created_at::date);
```

The above options are different options depending on the database. I do not know what does https://mode.com/online-sql-editor/ support.